# jQuery flot hover not working when user moves down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using [jQuery flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/). I can't seem to explain the bug well. But by the looks of it, the hover does not work when the user moves down to the page: Here's the video:
http://screencast.com/t/qZIjJ8jsi

Notice when i'm on top of my page the hover is working, but when I'll go down the page, then the hover on the points won't work.

My page is responsive(not sure if that's related, but just saying). Looks like this is a CSS problem. So here's my code:

```
var graphData = decodeURIComponent(jQuery("#graphData").val());
    graphData = jQuery.parseJSON(graphData);

    var visitors = new Array();
    var totalVisitors = 0;
    jQuery.each(graphData,function(index,value){
        visitors[index] = [value[0],value[1]];
        totalVisitors = totalVisitors + parseInt(value[1]);
    });

    jQuery(".date-figures").text(totalVisitors);
    var visitor = $("#activeUsers"),
    data_visitor = [{
        data: visitors,
        color: '#058DC7'
    }],
    options_lines = {
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                fill: true,
                fillColor: "#E5F3F9",
                color:"#058DC7",
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            },
            hoverable: true
        },
        grid: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: '#CDCDCD',
            hoverable: true
        },
        legend: {
            show: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
        },
        yaxis: {
           show:true
        },
    }; 
    $.plot(visitor, data_visitor, options_lines);
    function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none',
            top: y + 5,
            left: x + 5,
            padding: '2px 10px 2px 10px',
            opacity: 0.8,
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    }

    var previousPoint = null;
    $('#visitor-stat, #order-stat, #user-stat,#activeUsers').bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                $("#tooltip").remove();
                var d = new Date(item.datapoint[0]);
                var day = parseDay(d.getDay());
                var date = d.getDate();
                var month = parseMonth(d.getMonth());
                var year = d.getFullYear();
                var tooltipWording = "<b>"+day+", "+month+" "+date+", "+year+"</b>";
                tooltipWording += "<ul>";
                tooltipWording += "<li>Visits: <b>"+item.datapoint[1]+"</b></li>";
                tooltipWording += "</ul>";
                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, tooltipWording);
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;            
        }
    });
});
```

What seems to be problem here? Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: That looked strange actually. Do you have any `scroll`-related code? any overlay element that could prevent the mouse hover from being listened on the correct element?

Comment: What version of Flot are you using exactly?  Are you using any plugins?  What does your HTML and CSS look like for #activeUsers?

Comment: @Sergio and @ DNS I noticed that this is just happening in Mozila Firefox. Not sure why. By the way this is the theme that i'm usin http://nightskyadmin.com/demo-bs3/template/dashboard.html try to check their graph. Thank you very much for your help guys!

Comment: It does definitely seem like a CSS issue, but I can't offer much more without being able to inspect the live site.